# RecyclerView GridLayoutAdapter - How to center items

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView with GridLayoutAdapter. Is it possible to center items horizontally or vertically?

My item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_photo_image_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/custom_photo_item_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_photo_item_size"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_image_background"
        tools:src="@drawable/gallery_list_cars"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Actually it looks like this: http://oi61.tinypic.com/34pjmtc.jpg

Desired layout should look like: http://oi62.tinypic.com/7e2t.jpg

Setting RecyclerView to wrap_content does not work, it still uses all free space. I imagine it should be LayoutManager responsibility to setup children gravity within RecyclerView.

Comment: ever get an answer for this that works?

Comment: No. I ended up hardcoding RecyclerView width and centering it horizontally in the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already did with that line:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

With that line you already Center the `ImageView` horizontal and vertical.

If you just want one of them use for example:

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

I don't know what exactly is your Problem, we do not even know

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/custom_photo_item_size"
```

which value is declared in your `dimensions.xml`...

If you want to Center your whole `Item` you would Need to declare:

```
android:layout_gravity="Center"
```

but this doesn't make any sense as you only have one layout in a `GridView-Cell` and you declared your `rootView` of your Item as

```
android:width="match_parent"
android:height="match_parent"
```

So this is just an info for you ;)

Provide more Infos if you want better Support. Hope it helps anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
```

Adapter's xml parent layout set
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).